The most pythonic way to make a list / a generator with limits
I would like to plot a function in matplotlib, but only in a range bounded by two floats, say 2.6 and 8.2.  For that I need a list or a generator that includes two float bounds, such as
[2.6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8.2]

I know this can be done like this
lst = [2.6]
lst.extend(list(range(ceil(2.6), ceil(8.2))))
lst.append(8.2)

but this is very quirky.  Is there any better pythonic way to do that?

If the bounds are 0.0 and 10.0, what should the output be? Should the output start with [0.0, 0, [0.0, 1, or something else? Should it end with 9, 10.0], 10, 10.0], 9], or something else?

Your requirements are quirky so perhaps a quirky solution is to be expected.

@JohnColeman Possibly you are right.  What I actually need is actually not that quirky - I want to plot a function in matplotlib, but only in a certain float range.

@user2357112 I have reedited the question to make my requirements clearer.

If you need it for plotting purposes then why do you care if the intermediate points are integers? Wouldn't it make more sense to have equally spaced points?

You can write it as lst = [2.6, *range(floor(2.6) + 1, ceil(8.2)), 8.2] and replace the numbers by variables. Rounding errors may produce wrong results though.

Your requirements are not clear at all. Since you seem to have a working example, can you include a [mcve] with the plot in your question? plt.xlim(2.6, 8.2) might be all you need if you use range(10) for your x-values.

@JohnColeman Actually this ranges are of different lengths, so the number of points depends on the range.  Additionally, since I am plotting twice (once for the whole range in black and once only for the specified range in different colour), it would be a good that drawing points for those two plots coincide.

PEP 448's additional unpacking generalizations make this at least a little less verbose:
lst = [2.6, *range(ceil(2.6), ceil(8.2)), 8.2]

I'd personally wrap it in a function and document what/why you do this, but it works fine inlined, assuming the code makes more sense in context than it does lacking context here.
If lazy generation (single pass, no in-memory collection) is acceptable/desirable, you can use itertools.chain to make an iterator producing the same values:
from itertools import chain

gen = chain([2.6], range(ceil(2.6), ceil(8.2)), [8.2])

If the values being provided might themselves be even integers, you may want to use math.nextafter to ensure the range bounds don't overlap the start point, changing the range to:
range(ceil(math.nextafter(2.6, math.inf)), ceil(8.2))

for either solution above.

As a side-note, the list call in your original code was redundant; .extend takes any iterable, as does the list constructor, so if you can convert it to a list in the first place, you could pass it to extend directly and avoid the temporary list.

It is lazy generation, but I prefer simplicity of code to memory savings (unless huge lists are concerned).

nextafter seems more complicated than floor(2.6) + 1.

@nocomment: Sure, whatever floats your boat. I felt the logic of nextafter+ceil more closely matched the logical intent, but sure, it works either way.
